# Is There a Generic Theme Duplication Module or Drush Command

Tags: theming

As I understand there are Drush commands for Adaptive Theme, Omega, Zen and maybe other themes for creating subthemes, but is there a more generic module/way to create/duplicate a theme?  It would be nice to give clients a way to mirror their theme within the interface.

Comment: I don't think so, the closest I've seen is https://www.drupal.org/project/module_builder which can be hard to make work, but claims rudimentary support for theme generation.

Comment: If found this #!/bin/bash script reference to the ZEn them that looks like it would serve as base - https://www.drupal.org/node/276120 - although that brings up the question "can a bash script be run from PHP/Drupal" and/or why bother if it can be done in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

No but you can copy the theme folder and then replace the name of the theme in all hooks and of course rename yourtheme.info to yourcopy.info. in order not to miss any hook you may use a prog like wingrep and search-replace the yourtheme string

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of this but it does not give client "feel good" perception of Drupal in my experience.  Clients can use "save as" on their documents or copy folders of docs and rename folders/ files so they expect similar simplicity or i would like to give that option.

Comment: Seems module builder module might provide some tricks...